# I have a few questions about selenium and how to use CSS selectors and an error: 'selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException'

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x, selenium

I did a little bit of digging and I think I understand what CSS selectors are and what they look like, but using selenium, how can I search for a CSS selector in a site and then click on it? I don't really know what the syntax is supposed to look like.

I also got this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <div class="echo-component-EchoButton-3T1Xv">...</div> is not clickable at point (95, 328). 
Other element would receive the click: <div id="background" style="opacity: 1; overflow-y: auto; position: 
absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s; display: flex; 
align-items: baseline;">...</div>
```

From what I read, the "other element that would receive the click" looks like a CSS selector, so that is why I'm wondering how to use them and be able to interact with them. I'm new to selenium and reading HTML and CSS so please, correct me if I'm wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is your `div` inside of something clickable like an `a` or a `button`?

Comment: @pguardiario https://imgur.com/a/hH080NP This is where the the little x icon is to close a certain box that's in my way. I tried interacting with the "ico-close" id but I was unsuccessful. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. That's also why I was wondering if I could use the line "<svg focusable="false"...to interact with this x button

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see,
`Element <div class="echo-component-EchoButton-3T1Xv">...</div> is not clickable at point (95, 328).`
this probably means the element is not ready to be clicked. This can be solved by giving some time for the elements to loan prior to clicking it.

you could try reading or using these :

```
WebDriverWait 
sleep
```

both will allow some time for the elements to be ready.

For `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException` , i typically will include some exception handling into problematic areas. Can read about it here : `https://www.guru99.com/exception-handling-selenium.html`

example of what i normally do:

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fr66n .\\_8-yf5"))).click()

except TimeoutException:
    next_button = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next")
    next_button.click()

else:
    sleep(1)
    next_button = self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("Next")
    next_button.click()
```

you can also try to use selenium IDE. Really helps me to understand the process better.

Comment: I actually did add a time.sleep but it still didn't work which I thought was weird, so I think I did something wrong. But Your try except block has a little bit different syntax than the one that I saw in a tutorial, could you tell me what you import to make your answer possible? Out of curiosity as well, how did you call that CSS selector, that's what I don't understand, is it somewhere in the selector itself or in the same div? (not too familiar with the terminology). Thank you for the response @Kitten!

Comment: Yes, the except block was something i had handy. For you case should be : 
`except ElementClickInterceptedException:`, basically means that in the event this exception was raised, do somthing. I called by  `from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException`.
You can find most of the exception here : `https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/exceptions-selenium-python/`
i also suggest you try out selenium IDE, really helped me out in locating those CSS selectors